# Unable to import JsonPickle in Jupyter Notebook on Dataflow Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am building a pipeline on `Apache Beam` in python and am using the notebook on `Dataflow` for prototyping. While trying to load a JSON I realized that my JSON coder (basically `JSON.loads()`) that I used with `beam.io.ReadFromText(file_pattern, coder=JsonCoder())` does not normalize the JSON. This mean some of the columns in the collection were just nested JSON as string.

So to normalize the JSON, I decided to use `JsonPickle`. However, even after installing and restarting the kernel, the module import doesn't work. Can you please help? Also of there is a better way to normalize a JSON on `Apache Beam` world, please share.

[image]

Comment: Try running in the notebook: %pip install jsonpickle

Comment: @rmesteves worked like a charm

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the coder provide to transform `ReadFromText` can you just use the default coder and use a follow up `ParDo` to normalize/format the elements produced by the transform as you wish ? `Coder` should be considered as just a way for the Beam runner to serialize/deserialize elements produced by the transform. Using a `Coder` to format elements produced by a transform is an anti-pattern.

Comment: yes I followed your approach. I am using `ParDo` to unmarshell each line, then use JSON normalize in pandas to normalize the nested parts , convert the data frame and convert it back to JSON or dict before and pipe it to pipeline. I still feel this is very weird.

Answer (score 1):

According with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/dependencies), you need to run your command like below:

```
%pip install jsonpickle
```

Comment: Do you also have answer to my other predicament?

Comment: I think the best way for normalizing a JSON in Apache Beam is using a ParDo transform. There is a PTransform that parses jsons but I dont know if it applies to your case https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/jackson/ParseJsons.html

Comment: Actually this is for Java. For Python apparently its nor available